# Tests to check a non-linear relationship?

Tags: regression, nonlinear

I have a non-linear relationship between two variable (tested using a linear and square term). Are there any tests that can provide validation for the non-linear relationship?

I have tested Lind-Mehlum (2010) U test and that works. I was wondering whether there are other statistical tests that can support the quadratic relationship? Its an inverted-U shape.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about that, but you can test whether there is a linear, quadratic, cubic, etc. trend in the variables and response with contrasts inside the regression model.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: There are a very great many number of such tests.  One reason is that "nonlinearity" is an extremely broad and vague term, akin to "nonspherical" as a descriptor of shapes.  An effective test will take into account *specific forms of possible nonlinear behavior* that you might be concerned about.  Are you concerned about quadratic relationships (which are specific mathematical models), or about U-shaped relationships, or about some other form of nonlinearity?

Comment: I am specifically looking for an inverted U-shape relationship.